# can we get exact timing of google fit midnight reset?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-fit, google-fit-api

i want to know limitations of google fit API (Midnight reseting issue)

i want to develop android app which is include same as google fit using google fit's API it is possible?

I want details about Google Fit, When Day is changed(How it will manage)

Comment: What is "google fit API (Midnight reseting issue)"?

Comment: reset timing of googleFit at MidNight?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these limitations. It will be helpful.
[Activity Types](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types)   and
[Manage Google Fit's permissions](https://support.google.com/fit/answer/9488336?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)